# PL/SQL Remove unwanted characters from a phone number

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

I have looked around and cannot seem to find a straight answer to this question. I am confused as to how I would do this. Should I be using a regular expression or is there a better way to do this.

I have a procedure that formats phone numbers depending on what they start with and how long they are. I want to be able to clean the phone number first, before formatting it. So my tutor has thrown in a phone number that looks like this

> 07A3345&6543

I want to remove the A and the & from the phone number before formatting it.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `translate()`.  One way is by being explicit about what you want to remove:

```
select translate(phone, '0123456789', '0123456789A&')
```

Another way is to be more clever and just keep the numbers:

```
select translate(phone, '0123456789' || translate(phone, 'a0123456789', 'a'), '0123456789')
```

This will drop all the non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to remove non-digit characters, you might try this:

```
TRANSLATE(phone,'0123456789'||phone,'0123456789')
```

This will map characters `0` through `9` to themselves, and any other character present in the phone number to *nothing* -- actually discarding them.

Given your example:

```
DECLARE
  phone VARCHAR(20) := '07A3345&6543';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TRANSLATE(phone,'0123456789'||phone,'0123456789'));
END
```

Will display:

```
0733456543
```